# Stopping and restarting foreground service scanning with altbeacon

Tags: android, android-notifications, altbeacon

I'm currently getting a headache with sticky notifications while trying to stop and restart foreground scanning in altbeacon.

**What I want to do:** 
I want to start scanning for Bluetooth LE Beacons in a vehicle after the User presses a Button in my App. The App should notice if the User leaves his vehicle (event region left) and perform some actions. After that, the User can go back to the login screen and start the process again.
The Beacon detection should still be working when the app is minimized.

**My current solution:**
I implemented Altbeacon in my Application class. In the Applications onCreate, I initialize the BeaconManager (getInstance, set BeaconParsers, etc.).
When the user clicks the button, I call `startMonitoring` to start a foreground scan:

```
public void startMonitoring() {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationicon);
    builder.setContentTitle("Content Title");
    builder.setContentText("Content Text");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ChannelId", "ChannelName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder.setChannelId(channel.getId());
    }

    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 12345);
    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);

    beaconManager.bind(this);
}
```

When I detect that the User left the vehicle, I call `stopMonitoring` to stop the foreground scan and remove the notification:

```
public void stopMonitoring() {
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
    beaconManager.disableForegroundServiceScanning();
}
```

Disabling the foreground scan should normally remove the sticky notification or at least make it removable (by swiping) to the user. This isn't the case.
I was able to remove the notification by deleting the notification channel:

```
public void stopMonitoring() {
    [...]

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel("ChannelId");
    }
}
```

But when I do this, the app won't show the notification again.

Does anyone have an idea on how to stop and restart foreground scanning properly?

Comment: Calling `beaconManager.unbind(this)` should stop the scanning service, and when the service stops, the notification should go away by itself.  I suspect the service may not be stopping for an unknown reason.  Can you set beaconManager.setDebug(true); Then capture a LogCat excerpt after you call unbind?  Look for lines from the BeaconService class to see if it is shutting down.

Comment: I'm getting these two `Not stopping scan because this is Android N and we keep scanning for a minimum of 6 seconds at a time.` `Not stopping scanning.  Device capable of multiple indistinct detections per scan.` about every 100ms.
Could that really be causing the Problem?

Comment: Ok, nevermind. While analyzing the logs I found [this issue](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/764) and realized that the version I implemented isn't the latest anymore, I was still using Version 2.15.2.
I updated to 2.16.1 and it works just fine now.
Thank you very much, without the debug feature I probably would have searched for hours.